# TS-plugin underline almost all lines as error in vue files

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I've wanted to make a project on Vue with TypeScript. I've created project by vue-cli, checked TypeScript and eslint standard, rest was default.
Everything works great, but ts-plugin in VS code underlines everything as an error in .vue files.
I've set all settings in VS code to default and I have vetur as plugin with Vue pack.

I have other projects on JavaScript and I have never had similar problems.

How can I fix it?

[image: TS-plugin errors in vue file]

Comment: Try starting IDE with all extensions disabled and the  enabling just Vetur.

Answer (score 0):

check if the file extension is **.vue**, not .js (or .ts in your case)
for example, App.vue, not App.js